# How to create a LookUpTable[LUT] PNG file?

Tags: opengl-es, png, lookup-tables

I want to load a color lookup table as a Sampler2D in the fragment shader, and how to create such a png file like below?

[image: a LUT png]

Help me, please.

Answer (score 0):

OK.I work it out, and just draw the colors on a CGContext and save as a PNG file.
Before drawing, turning off anti-aliasing.

```
CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(context,0);
```